# Making Android device appear as a drive in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, android

I have an Android device (Asus Memo 8) that appears correctly as a 'Device' in Windows 8.

The issue being that I want it to mount as a 'Drive' so that I can reference it directly by name eg. D:\

This is for the purposes of having file transfers initiated from the command line and I am not sure how do to so as a 'Device'.

How can I force the device to appear as a drive, making it easier to reference from other programs?

[image: Yes, it is a very stupid device name as well]

Comment: This is up to the Android device to support.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your device to your PC using USB. Then go to Settings -> Storage -> menu: USB computer connection -> select: Mass storage.

A dialog will also appear and you have to click the big button to enable the USB mass storage.

If it doesn't work, install Android USB drivers.